# ImageView moves when scaled/rotated

Tags: android

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:id="@+id/globeViewStreamInfoPanel"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/streamIndicator"
               android:src="@drawable/nv_tidestreamindicator"
               android:scaleType="matrix"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_margin="10dp"
               android:maxHeight="40dp"
               android:maxWidth="40dp"
               android:layout_width="40dp"
               android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

Code (`streamIndicator` is the `ImageView`):

```
streamIndicatorMatrix.reset();
streamIndicatorMatrix.setScale(size,size);

// rotate indicator in the direction of the flow
streamIndicatorMatrix.setRotate((float)(stream.currentStream.direction));

streamIndicator.setImageMatrix(streamIndicatorMatrix);
```

When I rotate, or scale, or both, the ImageView moves in the layout.

Weird thing is, when I break on the line after `setImagematrix` and inspect `streamIndicator`, `mTop`, `mLeft`, `mWidth` and `mHeight` all look correct.  `size` and my rotation angle are always legal, sensible values.

I just know this is something stupid, what have I missed?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Here's a pic, the red arrow was added by me to point to the errant ImageView:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Matrix.setRotate` uses the `(0, 0)` pivot point by default. This is the reason your image moves in the layout. There is a overloaded version of the `Matrix.setRotate` method that allows you to speficy the pivot point.

```
final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final int center = Math.round(20 * density);

streamIndicatorMatrix.setScale(size,size, center, center);
streamIndicatorMatrix.setRotate((float)(stream.currentStream.direction), center, center);
```

Comment: Doh!.  You know what's even more annoying is that if someone had asked me that question, I would have given them that answer!  I guess I've put too many hours into this lately :)  THANK YOU!

Comment: can you help me...? @Vladimir Mironov,.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023108/android-how-to-scaley-to-based-on-other-objects-position