# Android : how to ScaleY to based on other Object's Position?

Tags: java, android, image, object, scale

this is android based question.

[image]

Here I have 2 Objects :

1. Springs, 1.Box (objectMass)

I then tried to move the box to certain position below using this code:

```
objMass.setTranslationY((float) y_newPost);
```

But then my question is related to the Springs object. How do I ensure that the bottom of the springs follow to the position of the Box after its movement? Perhaps scaling is the answer, but to be honest, should I calculate the height of the Springs first, then doing the scaling-Y of the Springs or how? Please share a bit of code as well...

The Box (object Mass) and the Spring are using this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kotak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/box" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pegas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/springs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```